# Macbook and MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, macos

I'm using mongoDB for an application following a tutorial here you have the [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k_0ZzvHbNBQ). While installing mongodb, I'm stuck at 9:50 and the command run to start mongod is `mongod --directoryperdb --dbpath c:\mongodb\data\db --logpath c:\mongodb\log\mongo.log --logappend -rest --install`

On my Mac I have my project and mongo directory on my desktop so I installed mongod following the above video. While starting mongod pointing to a different data directory using `mongod --directoryperdb --dbpath /Usr/me/Desktop/mongodb/data/db --logpath /Usr/me/Desktop/mongodb/log/mongo.log --logappend -rest --install` am having issues.

and it doesn't work (I have also copied the bin files to my `local/bin` directory

Below is the error.

```
events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
MongoError: failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect [MongoError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017]
    at Pool.<anonymous> (/Users/houssamtoulni/Desktop/proget/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:328:35)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Pool.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at Connection.<anonymous> (/Users/houssamtoulni/Desktop/proget/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:280:12)
    at Connection.g (events.js:292:16)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/houssamtoulni/Desktop/proget/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:177:49)
    at Socket.g (events.js:292:16)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at emitErrorNT (net.js:1277:8)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
```

Comment: Did you mean `/Users/me` instead of `/Usr/me`?

Comment: Also, do the mongodb folders exist in the Desktop folder? Did mongod finish starting without problems?

Comment: Can you run `ps -eaf | grep mongod` command to check whether mongod is running?

Comment: There appears to be a fundamental misunderstanding here of how a database works. Most of the content here refers to *"copy to my local directory"* which is not something you do. Instead just run the instance on the machine. Your "project" is completely separate to what the database is, and it just "uses" the database like any remote service. So there is no need to set up a `mongod` instance for each "project" you have. Your project is just "code" that "connects" to a service.